# MagicUsageError: Cannot read notebook when debug pipelines

Tags: azure-synapse

I am trying to run pipelines in develop branch (collaboration branch) in azure synapse.

The following error raise:

```
{
    "errorCode": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Operation on target Processing_1 failed: MagicUsageError: Cannot read notebook /folder_1/confs. The possible reason is that the notebook doesn't exist. More details please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2173018\n--> PartnerException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Analytics.SynapseNotebookService.Infrastructure.Exceptions.ClientExceptions.PartnerException' was thrown.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Pipeline_1",
    "details": ""
}
```

I see that my notebooks well exist.

I guess the error I have done is that I did modification directly on the branch "develop". "Publish" button is clickable on this branch. Maybe the error is raised because it waits "Publish". Modifications have be done on other branch and pull request on develop branch is done so **I don't need to publish what I have done on develop branch.**

How can I solve the problem ?